# Reverse struct in octave

Tags: matlab, hash, octave, cell-array

I implemented a struct in octave like this:

```
words = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "};

hash = struct;
for word_number = 1:numel(words)
    hash = setfield(hash, words{word_number},word_number);
endfor
```

This is like a hashmap of the form : {'a':1,'b':2....}

I want the reverse form of this struct of the form : {1:'a',2:'b'.....}

Edit: I tried to reverse it but was getting the error because keys can't be integer in struct as pointed out by Mr. Divakar in the answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and... what have you tried? what problems did you find?

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: I was getting problem in mapping int value to char. Any solution?

Comment: welcome to SO, this way of asking is not appropiate; demonstrate some research effort on your part, and come back in case you have more precise questions; we will then be happy to help.

Comment: @newuser - Did you end up trying what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names or structure fieldnames must not start with numerals. If you are getting any error, it might be because of that. So, to avoid this issue, use a common keyword and append the numerals to it.

If you prefer a no-loop approach -

```
%// Declare the keyword that doesn't start with any numeral
keyword = 'field_'

%// This might be a more efficient way to create a cell array of all letters that 
%// uses ascii equaivalent numbers
words = cellstr(char(97:97+25)') 

%// Set fieldnames
fns = strcat(keyword,strtrim(cellstr(num2str([1:numel(words)]'))))

%// Finally get the output
hash = cell2struct(words, fns,1)
```

Output -

```
hash = 
     field_1: 'a'
     field_2: 'b'
     field_3: 'c'
     field_4: 'd'
     field_5: 'e'
     field_6: 'f' ...
```

Comment: The problem is, I need to use the integer key in a function as I am using  getfield(hash,code) where code is an integer starting from 1.

Comment: @newuser Try this - `getfield(hash,strcat(keyword,num2str(code)))`

Comment: Yeah. It worked! Thanks a lot! I want to add a space character too. like : field_27: ' '. How should I add it?

Comment: No, space in the struct added in the end like: field_27 = " "

Comment: @newuser Right after declaring `words`, use this - `words(end+1) = {' '}`. Rest of the code stays the same. Whatever character you would like to add, just use that format. So, for adding `$`, it would be `words(end+1) = {'$'}`.

Comment: @newuser Awesome! Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

One would think that you could simply reverse the second and third parameters in the `setfield` function, but numeric fields are not supported for `structs` in Octave / MATLAB.  What you could possibly do is use [`num2str`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html) to transform each number into a string.  You can then use this field to access in  your struct.  In other words, try this:

```
hash_reverse = struct;
for word_number = 1:numel(words)
    hash_reverse = setfield(hash_reverse, num2str(word_number), words{word_number});
endfor
```

Now, to access your fields, you would simply call `getfield`:

```
val = getfield(hash_reverse, num2str(num));
```

`num` is the number you want to use.  For example, if we wanted the value using the field of 3:

```
val = getfield(hash_reverse, num2str(3));
%// or 
%// val = getfield(hash_reverse, "3");
```

This is what I get:

```
val = 

c
```